# Stored Procedure Call In Code, Possible To Change FROM Clause? C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using the following generic method, where the string `StoredProcedureName` specifies a name of a stored procedure in my database. The `args` parameter is the arguments I am passing to my stored procedure.

```
private static SqlCommand GetSqlCmd(object[] args, string connectionString)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     string sprocFullName = string.Format("[{0}].dbo.[{1}]", conn.Database, StoredProcedureName);
     SqlCommand ret = new SqlCommand(sprocFullName, conn)
     {
         CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     };

     for (int i = 0; i < ParameterCount; i++)
     {
         ParameterInfo p = Parameters[i];
         object arg = args[i];

         if ((arg != null) && ReferenceEquals(arg.GetType(), typeof (DateTime)))
         {
            if (((DateTime) arg).Ticks.Equals(0))
            {
               arg = DBNull.Value;
            }
         }

         ret.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.Name, arg ?? DBNull.Value);
     }

     return ret;
 }
```

Here is a truncated example of one of stored procedure, simple `SELECT` query, nothing fancy. In the stored procedures, the string [this is what I want to replace] is the reason for my question.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SelectSOMETHING] 
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT [SOMETHING]
    FROM [this is what I want to replace].[table] 

    COMMIT
```

The `FROM`, where it specifies where the database is to run this against, can this be changed using the following generic method as specified in the above part of my question? The table name is a constant, however I would like to supply the database value from a config file. Am I just not seeing the property for it?

TIA experts!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get a stored procedure to run dynamically built SQL, but you have to be careful as this is a potential cause for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://colinmackay.co.uk/2005/04/23/sql-injection-attacks-and-some-tips-on-how-to-prevent-them/). It would be better to no have to do this, so if there is a way of not requiring you pass in a database name that would be much better. e.g. connecting to the right database to begin with. I do appreciate that there are times when this is not possible, so for those instances the solution below should be a good mix of safety and getting what you want.

You can build your SQL Statement in a string (`NVARCHAR(MAX)`) and then use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute it. When it comes to the point of injecting your database name, remember to use [QUOTENAME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to escape the name, so that users of the stored proc cannot inject dodgy values that will damage your database.

It is also useful to validate that the database exists before trying to execute the SQL by checking against [sys.databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)

e.g.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE Name = @databaseName)
BEGIN
    -- Build & Execute your dynamic SQL here
END
```

Comment: I'll give you +1 because you went into such detail... but it's not right that you left negative comments on two other peoples answers who also in effect suggested the same thing you did.

Comment: They didn't give the same answer. One didn't think about the SQL Injection Attack issue at all, and the other only vaguely mentioned it without detailing what the implications were. I at least linked off to an article that goes into the detail and put up front (first sentence) that you have to be careful because of the possible attack issues.

SQL Injection attacks are (consistently) at the number one spot on OWASP threats to web applications year-after-year, and the only reason it is still there is that people don't think about it properly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you pass the dbname from c# as a parameter into dynamic sql, then execute the dynamic sql.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SelectSOMETHING] (@dbname NVARCHAR(100))
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT [SOMETHING] 
                FROM '+@dbname+'.dbo.[table]'
    EXEC(@SQL)
```

I removed your begin/commit transaction -- you don't need a transaction when you're just querying.

Comment: Good grief, NO! That way SQL Injection attacks lie.

Comment: If your users are passing the dbname, yes... but he said its in a config file.  You could do parameterized sql too, its safer when it comes to injections.  But Craig's response is better.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to it, e.g. @Database

then build the query and execute it

e.g.

Declare @sql VarChar(1000)
set @sql = 'Select [something] From ' + @Database + '.[table]'
exec(sql)

for example

Make sure nothing horrible can go in as the db parameter. I'd usually do maybe an enum map for this sort of thing

Comment: So, if I pass in the value of database as `;DELETE FROM Users--` What happens to the SQL Statement you're executing? One SQL Error, but the second command will still be run despite the error on the first.

Comment: Better to write the SQL up-front in a protected way so that even if a dodgy value gets through it isn't going to damage things. e.g. use `QUOTENAME` to escape the value in `@Database`

Comment: Put a whitelist case statement in the sp would be an improvement, checking that @tablename is a an accessible db would be icing on the cake. On those unfortunate occasions where you do have to concatenate strings into sql, there are a numbers of hoops you should jump through. Note if setting the db in the connection string was a viable solution, the question is pointless, you'd just create the sp in that database. And any of these solutions assumes application level security. Better is optional the real world of commercial software.